# Is gwt-graphics 0.9.3 compatible with gwt 2.0.3

Tags: gwt, vaadin

I am using [gwt graphics(vaadin)](http://vaadin.com/web/hene/wiki/-/wiki/Main/GWT%20Graphics%20Manual;jsessionid=591AF166DFFD20E90A118E772363AAAE#section-GWT+Graphics+Manual-SettingUpTheLibraryInYourProject) for one of my project, till yesterday i had gwt1.7.1 and all the drawing objects were working fine. For some reason i had to install eclipse again and so now i have gwt 2.0.3. I am observing few problems with graphics now, like the text is not getting positioned properly, if i do any changes to the code, concerned to drawing objects, it is not showing up. Therefore wanted to know whether gwt-graphics0.9.3 was compatible with gwt 2.0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I had to install a plug-in for firefox and everything started to execute properly.
Thank you.

Comment: What plugin? Vaadin should not be depending on any plugins.

Comment: I think it has got to do with gwt 2.0 i believe that it requires plugin to work properly with firefox. as vaadin is tied to gwt may be it was not working properly. Once i installed the plugin it is working fine now.